# Springfox swagger html not working with apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache, spring-boot, swagger, reverse-proxy, springfox

I have my swagger-ui.html file displaying correctly for my spring boot app in my local dev environment.  However, when I deploy my app with Apache, it does not work.  I am guessing my apache configuration may be wrong.  Any help greatly appreciated.

In my httpd.conf file I have this :

`ProxyPass /myAppSwagger http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui.html
 ProxyPassReverse /myAppSwagger http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui.html`

This is my swagger config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {                                    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() { 
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
          .select()                                  
          .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.boot")))              
          .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
          .build().directModelSubstitute(Timestamp.class, Long.class);
    }


}
```

This renders the swagger like this:
[image]

Comment: See the browser console, detect which files ( `css`, `js` ) are not loaded.

Comment: Thanks Ataur,  it looks like there are MANY css and js files 404ing.  Trying to figure out what to do about this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem. It turned out that my apache httpd.conf was wrong.
Once I fixed the VirtualHost section of my apache configuration, swagger is able to load all needed resources.

Thank you to Ataur Rahman Munna for pointing me in the right direction.  I needed to edit httpd.conf to turn on "ProxyPreserveHost" and fix my ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse values to just point at the root of my app, not at swagger-ui.html.

*note : 
To get to my rest endpoints I use

`http://myapUrl/myApp`.

To get to my swagger document I use

`http://myappUrl/myAppSwagger/swagger-ui.html`

I did not have to change any code to get this to work, it was simply editing my apache httpd.conf file to have this content that made this work :

`<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On 
  ProxyPass /myApp http://localhost:8081/myApp
  ProxyPassReverse /myApp http://localhost:8081/myApp 
  ProxyPass /myAppSwagger http://localhost:8081/
  ProxyPassReverse /myAppSwagger http://localhost:8081/

</VirtualHost>`

See here for info on [Enabling the Apache ProxyPreserveHost directive](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40518_01/studio.310/studio_install/src/cidi_studio_reverse_proxy_apache_proxypreservehost.html)